# Bash sed find and replace matching to first instance

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a string `<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>DATAbase</th>` and I want to remove '`bgcolor=#7070ff`' between the `<TH and >` using

```
echo '<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>DATAbase</th> ' | sed "s/\<TH.*\>/<th>/"
```

However this produces `<th>`  rather than `<TH> DATAbase </th>`

Can anyone explain to me why sed is matching to the second instance of '>' please?

Reading through the [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) I can't figure it out!

**EDIT**:

```
echo '<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>DATAbase</th> ' | sed 's|\(<TH[^<]*>\)|<th>|g'
```

This seems to work, but I don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this sed command,

```
sed 's|<TH[^>]*>|<th>|g' file
```

**Examples:**

If you want to retain the first `<TH>` as it is.

```
$ echo '<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>DATAbase</th> ' | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\)[^>]*\(.*\)$/\1\2/g'
<TH>DATAbase</th>
```

If you want the `<TH>` in small letters then try this,

```
$ echo '<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>DATAbase</th> ' | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\)[^>]*\(.*\)$/<th\2/g'
<th>DATAbase</th>
```

More simpler one without capturing groups,

```
$ echo '<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>DATAbase</th> ' | sed 's|<TH[^>]*>|<th>|g'
<th>DATAbase</th>
```

**Explanation:**

- `<TH[^>]*>` Matches the characters from `<TH` upto the next `>` character zero or more times followed by the symbol `>`. So it matches the string `<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>`. This matched string was replaced by `<th>`.

Comment: sed: illegal option -- r  bash shell

Comment: wait. updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj, what's the difference between using / and | in the sed command?

Comment: @liz_ophiuchus if the input contains `/` use a different sed delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo '<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>DATAbase</th> ' | sed "s/<TH[\w =#[:alnum:]]*>/<th>/"
```

Comment: No luck - $ echo '<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>DATAbase</th> ' | sed "s/\<TH.*?\>/<th>/"
<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>DATAbase</th>